# scons ParseConfig behaving incorrectly with wx-config on windows

Tags: c++, python, mingw, wxwidgets, scons

I am trying to use wx-widgets with scons on Windows using MinGW. This is the offending line of my SConstruct:

```
env.ParseConfig("wx-config --cxxflags --libs")
```

Immediately after this, printing env['CPPPATH'] gives:

```
['C:software_libwxWidgets2.8libgcc_dllmsw', 'C:software_libwxWidgets2.8include']
```

which, obviously, appears to be missing some very important slashes. I think it might have something to do with wx-config's windows port giving backslashes in its output.

These paths get passed verbatim to the compiler later, leading to errors. Everything else works great.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem with brute force. Wrote a helper python script consisting of the following:

```
import subprocess, sys

p = subprocess.Popen(["wx-config", "--cxxflags", "--libs"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()

san = out.replace("\\", "/")

sys.stdout.write(san)
sys.exit(0)
```

And ended up calling

```
env.ParseConfig("python sanitize-wx-config.py")
```

in the SConscript file. This solved the problem: